# MySQL join two tables, find max count and order by

Tags: mysql, join

I am rather newbie in SQL and before this moment I only used simple queries, but now I have a problem.
I have two tables. First is **rating**:

```
id  userid  value 
1   3       +
1   2       +
1   2       +
```

And second is **daybook**:

```
id  userid  week    day     lesson  content 
1   2       1       1       6       Test!
```

So now I have a problem. I need to:

**1)**  Join these tables by id.

**2)**  Then order results by count of entries in **rating** table.

So result must look like:

```
userid count
3      1
2      2
```

How to do that? Thanks for anything helpful.

Comment: have you tried any query at all?

Comment: Why do you even need the `daybook` table for this?

Comment: Maybe its because if there are no daybook entries, the corresponding rating entry shouldn't be displayed...maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select daybook.userid, count(*) as count 
    from daybook, rating 
    where daybook.userid = rating.userid
    group by daybook.userid
    order by count desc
```

But you dont even really need the daybook table:

```
select userid, count(*) as count
   from rating
   group by userid
   order by count desc
```

Comment: I probably need. Because I should only get ratings for specified id. If I replace id of one of the entries from 1 to 2, your code returns count = 2 for userid == 2, while I only need to get count = 1.

Comment: Okay then. I added "where id = 1" and this filters correctly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
SELECT count(id), rating.userid
FROM rating
JOIN daybook ON daybook.userid = rating.userid
GROUP BY userid
```