# Select the name from candidates table if he have highest entries in votes table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table in database
Table1: candidates

```
id | name
--------
1  | John
2  | Eva
3  | Siera
```

Table2: votes

```
| candidateid |
--------
|   1   |
|   1   |
|   1   |
|   1   |
|   2   |
|   2   |
|   3   |
```

Please someone help me my question is about to how can i select the name of person from candidates who have more entries in votes table.?

Comment: Is it mysql or sql server ?

Comment: @NomanKhan . . . Hint:  `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`.  What have you tried?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I used this but with this i get all of them in groups `SELECT voteId, count(voteId) FROM votes  GROUP by voteId`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it's mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL join two tables, find max count and order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743892/mysql-join-two-tables-find-max-count-and-order-by)

Comment: @NomanKhan, I added the mysql tag to your question. You should edit your question to add the code you've tried rather than as comments as that will help others better help answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do a simple JOIN between the two tables.
- Get total votes per candidate using `COUNT` function, over a grouping of candidate id.
- Order the result by total votes in descending order, and using `LIMIT 1` to get the details of the person with highest votes.

Try the following:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.name, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_votes 
FROM candidates AS c 
JOIN votes AS v ON v.candidateid = c.id 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `voteId` in your sample data.  You seem to want:

```
SELECT CandidateId, count(*)
FROM votes
GROUP by CandidateId;
```

You can use a `JOIN` to bring in the name from the other table.