# How to select the max table from join table?

Tags: mysql

I have table name `posts` and another table which name is `counttbl`

In my `post` table there is column name

```
postid(primarykey), postdetails, postdate(timestamp)
```

And in `counttbl` there are 3 column which are

```
id(primarykey), postid,countnumber
```

I want to select that post from `counttbl` which has `maximumnumber` of count,

E.g. in post table I have

```
postid = 1, postdetails = details1, date = 29:11:00 00:00:00
```

And in count there is `postid = 1`, `countnumber = 4`, and `postid = 2`, `countnumber = 3`

Then I want to select that post which has `maximumber` count number and show that post details using join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL join two tables, find max count and order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743892/mysql-join-two-tables-find-max-count-and-order-by)

Comment: Sir Can you provide answer

Comment: See the link you can make easily query by yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743892/mysql-join-two-tables-find-max-count-and-order-by

Comment: Have you done this?

Comment: not yet sir but i am trying it

Comment: Okay .there can be multiple value which have same countnumber ?

Comment: You will pick latest one?

Comment: yes i want to pick latest one , sir if possible can u write code please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184463/discussion-between-raghbendra-nayak-and-rahul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement would give you the desired result.
I named the tables and fields differen because of possible conflicts with reserved words in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT counts.postid, counts.counts 
  FROM counts 
  WHERE counts.counts = (SELECT max(counts) FROM counts) 
) tempcounts 
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.postid = tempcounts.postid 
ORDER BY posts.postdate DESC limit 0,1
```

If more post have the same count they all will be in the result

Comment: I want to select the last post which has maximum count

Comment: do mean that if there are several posts with the same maximum value you want the latest one? Then you have to sort by posts.postdate DESC and just use the first row in the result in mysql you could use LIMIT.

Comment: It is showing that data which is number one on counttbl not that data which has maximum count

Comment: `SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT
  counts.postid, 
  counts.counts 
 from counts 
 WHERE counts.counts = (SELECT max(counts) FROM counts)
    ) tempcounts
    INNER JOIN
    posts ON posts.postid = tempcounts.postid
 ORDER BY posts.postdate DESC limit 0,1`

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query:

```
SELECT MAX(cnt.countnumber), cnt.postid
FROM counttbl as cnt
JOIN post as pst ON cnt.postid = pst.id
```

I have given table name:

**Table name:** `post and counttbl`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
select * from posts p 
inner join 
(
  select postid, max(countnumber) from counttbl group by postid
) as p1
on p.postid=p1.postid
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from post where postid in (select postid from counttbl having max(countnumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from posts  WHERE post_id IN (select MAX(countnumber) from counttble )
```